# Get DB data at JQuery onchange textfield

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

I have confused how to deciding the way what I would take in MySQL.

I have 4 textfield:

```
<input type="text" id="model">
<input type="text" id="number">
<input type="text" id="line">
<input type="text" id="date">
```

then a Table in DB `Detail_model`:

```
+---------+-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|Model    |Line |Date       |Startnumber  |Endnumber  |
+---------+-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|Bear     |X01  |2013-04-26 |098X0001     |098X0100   |
|Cat      |X02  |2013-03-10 |098x0201     |098X0300   |
+---------+-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

If I type `Cat` at id=model and `098x0003` at id=number, I would get result :

```
Model        Line       Date
Cat          X02        2013-03-10
```

its means during onchange I send parameter `Cat` and `098X0003` into MYSQL Query.
TRY:

```
SELECT Model,Line, Date FROM Detail_model
WHERE Model LIKE 'Cat' AND .......(How to filter the number) ?
```

Comment: are startnumber and endnumber integer?

Comment: In another comment you mentioned that `number` may contain also characters and not only numbers.

Which order you like for `number` then? Alphabetical? Numerical with deleting non-digits first? Something else? You've to decide that, because you need that order when you want to retrieve results with a `number` between two others. Without defining this order `between` is undefined.

Comment: why I said that `number` may not only contains numbers because sometimes startnumber and endnumber have the case like that.

Comment: What is wrong with Chris U's answer? It looks like s/he replied to your question as it stands. Please clarify what result the proposed query returns and compare it to the actual result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Model,Line, Date FROM Detail_model
WHERE Model LIKE 'Cat' AND Startnumber <= '098x0003' AND Endnumber >= '098X0003'
```

This is what I get and I get the result.

Answer (score 2):

If startnumber and endnumber are integers you could select like that:

```
SELECT A.name,B.class, B.address FROM tableA AS A
LEFT JOIN tableB AS B
ON A.name = B.name
WHERE a.number >= b.startnumber AND a.number <= b.endnumber
```

Comment: @Chris: sometimes start and endnumber consist of number and character

Comment: @Nunu: So why you call it "number". It is extremly hard to select areas in fields that are not numbers because how do you determine, what "between" is. Do you have the create script of the table so that we perhaps find a solution.

Comment: @Chris: this like joining two different tables.

Comment: @Nunu: What do you want to join? Which tables? Do you have a table definition?

Comment: @Chris: I have changed my question.

Comment: @Chris: ya.I can do like that if data is already lies in DB, but how if I want to check this number before input data.I want to identify jody's ID use `CONCATENATION`.

Comment: @Nunu: I don't really know what you mean with that. Please explain more in detail.

Comment: @chris: i post the real situation.